# Get table name from edmx using t4 templates

Tags: entity-framework, t4, edmx

I am using database first approach. I already mapped my tables and have generated entities. In my edmx model I have changed table names so that my entity names are more readable. But now for some reason I need to get original table/column name for my entities. Is there anyway in which I can update tt file to get table/column names? (See desired code below).

// Current generated code for entity,

```
public partial class University
{
  public int DepartmentCount { get; set; }
}
```

// Desired code for entity,

```
[Description("TABLE_UNIVERSITY")]
public partial class University
{
  [Description("DEPARTMENT_COUNT")]
  public int DepartmentCount { get; set; }
}
```